# Http 403 forbidden when accessing applicaiton url from outside VM

Tags: apache, vmware, virtualization, http-status-code-403

I have an application running on  Linux OS on a VM. I am using VMWare. When I try to access the application url from outside the VM by providing the proper VM IP address I get a HTTP 403 forbidden in the browser. The application runs fine from within the VM on a browser when I use localhost to get to the app. I am able to ping the VM without any issue from the host system.

My network connection to the VM is NAT. I tried switching to the bridged connection but that didn't help. My host OS is Windows 10. Has anyone seen this behavior? Not sure if this question is elementary. I am very new to VMs.